# How To Pass Dropdown Values As Command Object And Upload To DB using Spring Framework

Tags: forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

new to Spring here. I have a scheduleLoad.jsp (below) that is to take user's dropdown list input and pass it to a confirmLoad.jsp screen and update the database.

```
Select Year:<form method="post" action="confirmLoadTest">
<select name="loadScheduleData">
<option value="2010-2011">2010-2011</option>
<option value="2011-2012">2011-2012</option>
<option value="2012-2013">2012-2013</option>
</select>
</form><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I'm having trouble with passing the command object in the controller with the loadScheduleData.
Here is the controller http://pastebin.com/G044Qn72. The commented code on the bottom is working code, but I'm trying to get the uncommented code to work. I'm not sure how to accept the inputs into a command object when the user hits "Submit" and pass it to my confirmLoad.jsp. Right now it's giving me the error:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springApp] in context with path [/SpringApp] threw exception [No adapter for handler [us.tx.state.tea.tsds.Controller.ScheduleLoadController@7c1b2e27]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [us.tx.state.tea.tsds.Controller.ScheduleLoadController@7c1b2e27]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler`

I've been trying to piece together code from these two tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!